# FirstPersonControls start by looking at an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

My camera.lookAt(cube.position); works only if I disable FirstPersonControls. How do I make so that I start my exploration by looking at first at my object ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

As of `three.js` R101, it's possible to use `FirstPersonControls.lookAt()`. `FirstPersonControls.lat` and `FirstPersonControls.lon` have been removed.